# Overload the [] or = operators for data changing in a linked list

Tags: c++

I want to know how to overload the operator [] or = so i can change the values in a linked list like in the vector class, for example.

```
 LinkedList list;
 list[0] = 2;
```

Comment: Both of those operators are described in the duplicate.

Comment: Note that overloading `operator[]` for a linked list is typically frowned upon, since use of `operator[]` is usually assumed to be sub-linear in cost (typically `O(1)`), while it would be `O(n)` for a linked list. You might take a look at `std::list` to get an idea of the API typically used for a linked list. `operator=` is for reassigning the *whole* list, so again, not appropriate for reassigning individual values. You'd want methods to insert and remove at a given iterator position, and assignable iterators, to allow inserting/removing/changing individual elements.